# console.log() a specific value in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to take a specific value in the JSON object below and send it to the console. How can I do this using `console.log()`?

I want to access specific cards in the object, but am currently not able to do so.

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "_id": "5e131eb4ea0c191cdc06f96b",
    "firstName": "Anirudh",
    "lastName": "Singla",
    "gender": "Male",
    "username": "anirudhsingla8",
    "email": "anirudhsingla8@gmail.com",
    "password": "rj13sl1608",
    "cards": [{
      "card_number": "1014220122322233",
      "shopping": 0,
      "food": 0
    }, {
      "card_number": "1014220122322233",
      "shopping": 0,
      "food": 0
    }, {
      "card_number": "1014220122322233",
      "shopping": 0,
      "food": 0
    }, {
      "card_number": "10353975236",
      "CVV": "192",
      "expiryYear": "342",
      "shopping": 0,
      "food": 0
    }, {
      "card_number": "88677677",
      "CVV": "987",
      "expiryYear": "57",
      "shopping": 0,
      "food": 0
    }, {
      "card_number": "88677677",
      "CVV": "987",
      "expiryYear": "57",
      "shopping": 0,
      "food": 0
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/); There's no [JSON](http://json.org) in your attempt of a question; [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `console.log(obj.data[0].cards);`

Comment: on using this command     console.log(obj.data[0].cards);
It is throwing this below error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (script.js:141)

Comment: What does  `console.log(typeof obj)` print?